# Pass Array to NSObject Class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iphone app development and I'm stuck on this problem I'm having with the app I'm trying to develop.

I have a datacontroller for populating a tableview. I created it using this tutorial:
[About Creating Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1)

I'm trying to pass an array from one of my viewcontrollers that was created from a JSON response.

Here is some code from my viewcontroller.h that needs to pass the array:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) DataController *Data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

viewcontroller.m:

```
  #import "DataController.h"
    [Data setMasterList: self.array];
```

DataController.h:

```
@interface DataController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *masterList;

- (void)setMasterList:(NSMutableArray *)newList;
@end
```

DataController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

    - (void)setMasterList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
          if (_masterList != newList) {
              _masterList = [newList mutableCopy];
          NSLog("List: %@", newList);


             }
          }
```

The NSLog message never shows up in the console and the array is nil.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's the updated viewcontroller.m:

```
Data = [[DataController alloc] init];
[Data setMasterList: self.array];
```

The datacontroller.m:

```
- (void)setMasterList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
      if (_masterList != newList) {
          _masterList = [newList mutableCopy];
      NSLog("List: %@", self.masterList);


         }
}

- (NSUInteger)countOfList {
    NSLog("List: %@", self.masterList);
    return [self.masterList count];
}
```

The first nslog inside setMasterList returns the correct array values, but the second nslog inside countOfList returns null. The list always returns null anywhere outside of setMasterList. Is it because I'm creating a new instance of the DataController? If so, how else could I pass the array to the datacontroller.

Comment: Is `Data` actually not `nil` when invoking `setMasterList:`? Check that by adding an NSLog just before calling `setMasterList:` (`NSLog(@"Data is %@", Data);`). btw never ever use capital initials for instance variables. Rename it to `data` or something.

Comment: Also, get rid of the declaration for `setMasterList:` in the `DataController.h` file. The property gives you this implicitly.

Comment: I added the NSLog and it comes up with (null). Thanks.

Comment: So this is solved, right? You understand that you have no DataController object?

Comment: Sorry, no I guess I don't understand. How would i make a DataController object?

Comment: So the problem seems to be that `self.array` is `nil`, since that's what you pass to `setMasterList:`, but your code doesn't actually show how that is initialized... (well, it obviously isn't, but you could at least show how you're *trying* to initialize it)

Comment: Intitialize the DataController object,& also cross check your array initialization.

Comment: the problem is that the first time you run the command setMasterList, both _masterList that NewList are nil, so they are equal. you have to change your condition. add a double check in case they are both to nil.

Answer (score 2):

As in first comment Till have suggested, `Data` must be initialized before calling `setMasterList`. Such As:

```
Data = [[DataController alloc] init];
[Data setMasterList: self.array];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I put an NSLog in the datacontroller and it's outputting the correct array. However, when I try to use it outside of setMasterList, it becomes nil. How can I use it in other areas of the datacontroller class?

Comment: Write `Data = [[DataController alloc] init];` line in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: try using `self.Data` instead of only `Data`, every where, as i can see Data is property.

Comment: I tried that, but it's still returning null outside of setMasterList

Comment: Update your latest cod in that case, so we can check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30175/discussion-between-rptwsthi-and-thomas-spade)